# Swiftui iOS14.5 Keyboard hides DatePicker but works perfectly for TextField

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, keyboard

On click of TextField inside a ScrollView, the keyboard appears and the TextField moves up perfectly as expected.

Time 1 DatePicker gets completely hidden by the keyboard, whereas Time 2 DatePicker doesn't hide but has no keyboard unless clicked again.

[image: TextField vs DatePicker behavious]

How do I get the keyboard for DatePicker to behave the same as it does for the TextField?

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
@State private var text = ""
@State private var date = Date()

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<15) { i in
                TextField("TextField \(i): ", text: $text)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            }
            DatePicker("Time 1: ", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en_GB"))
                .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            
            DatePicker("Time 2: ", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en_GB"))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's probably a bug in ios-14.5. 
It works well in ios-15, since the keyboard does not appear to change the date.

Comment: Tried on iOS15, it seems to have similar DatePicker hiding behavior, typing on the time selection pop-up using the keyboard covers the DatePicker.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You are correct, it does not work on ios 15. 
I thought you were taking about the keyboard for DatePicker behaviour, 
covering the other datePicker.